# laravel - user() object is null on Controller constructor

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I need to check on every controller to sth about logged user but when I do:

```
class ManagementController extends Controller
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        dd(Auth::user());
    }
}
```

I'm always getting `null`, in another methods everythink is fine - where is the problem?

Comment: To check logged User in constructor use `middleware` `$this->middleware('auth');`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do this in a controller constructor because the session wasn't initialized yet.

Comment: Ok, I understand. Do you have any another idea for my problem? I need to check in every route/controller spiecified property of user.

Comment: @David it depends on what exactly you're trying to achieve. For example, if you want to check if a user has access to some resources, you should use policies.

Comment: I need to check on column for value and if it's true, always redirect user to specified route, sth like "You must change password"

Comment: @David use middleware.

Comment: I tried and situation is same as in question (I created my own and registered it in Kernel after auth middlewares)

Comment: @David just tried to use `auth()->user()` object in middleware and it works just fine in 5.5.